# Create a script for walking back and forth in a game? Using Auto Hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

i'm trying to create a little script to walk back and forth in a game.

This is what i've wrote so far..

```
IfWinExist, Nox App Player
MouseMove, 2531, 418
WinActivate, Nox App Player
Send, {W down}
Sleep, 10000
Send, {W up}
Send, {S down}
Sleep, 10000
Send, {S up}
```

It do not seems like it recognize that he hold downs the following keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Sendinput, {w down}".